# How to store domain reference as a dynamic attribute of another domain in Grails with MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm

I would like to be able to store a reference to a domain object as a dynamic attribute of another domain.
Unfortunately, when I try to save such domain object I get:

```
| Error 2013-02-18 14:03:09,352 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: can't serialize class Employee
Message: can't serialize class Employee
```

Here's the code [Machine & Employee are domains]:

```
def m = new Machine(name: "Machine 01")
def e = Employee.findByName("employee name")
m['operator'] = e
m.save(failOnError: true)
```

I'm wondering if this is possible? I think it should, there are no limitations listed on mongodb plugin [I'm using 1.1.0GA with Grails 2.2.0].

```
class Machine {
    String name
}

class Employee {
    String name
}
```

Comment: What does the Machine domain class look like?

Comment: let's assume they look like this. I've edited the code.